# Here Maps - infobubble reposition in viewport

Tags: here-api

I'm upgrading an application from Here Maps Javascript API v2 to v3.

In v2, the infobubbles re-position in the viewport so they stay on the screen (e.g. if it's on the left of the viewport, then the infobubble re-positions to the right so it doesn't appear off screen)

This behaviour no longer exists in v3 of the Here Maps JS API.  The infobubble stays put all the time.  I can't find any settings for this - is it possible to get this old behaviour back?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution to this so rolled my own code to make it happen.
Here it is in case it helps anyone out ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () {        
        if ($('.H_ib_body').is(':visible')) {
            var top = parseInt($('.H_ib_top').css('transform').split(',')[5]);
            var left = parseInt($('.H_ib_top').css('transform').split(',')[4]);
            var height = $('.H_ib_body').height();
            if ($('.H_ib_body').attr('data-isBottom') != '1') { // on top
                if (height - top > 0) {
                    {
                        $('.H_ib_body').css('bottom', 'auto').css('top', '0em').attr('data-isBottom', '1');
                        $('.H_ib_tail').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
                    }
                }
            } else { // on bottom
                var totalHeight = $('#map canvas').height();
                if ((top + height) > totalHeight) {
                    $('.H_ib_body').css('bottom', '.5em').css('top', 'auto').attr('data-isBottom', '0');
                    $('.H_ib_tail').css('transform', '');
                }
            }
            if ($('.H_ib_body').attr('data-isRight') != '1') { // on left
                if (left - $('.H_ib_body').width() < -30) {
                    $('.H_ib_body').css('right', 'auto').css('left', '-20px').attr('data-isRight', '1');
                }
            } else { // on right
                var totalWidth = $('#map canvas').width();
                if (left + $('.H_ib_body').width() > totalWidth) {
                    $('.H_ib_body').css('right', '0px').css('left', 'auto').attr('data-isRight', '0');
                }
            }
        }
    }, 20);
});
```